# What would be the best textbook for a philosophy of mind intro course for psychology majors?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, psychology, cognitive-sciences

My area of expertise is logic and philosophical logic, but I'll be teaching an introductory course on the philosophy of mind to second semester psychology majors (taking cognitive science as a minor). Could someone recommend a textbook?

I probably don't want to bog those students down with unnecessarily heavy terminology and deep analysis (as per analytic philosophy), but rather spark their interest in the field.

When I majored in philosophy, philosophy of mind was a second year course, so we've had all the introductory courses under our belt. But here I won't have enough time to introduce all that. Or perhaps that's exactly what I should do in the first couple of weeks? I imagine there would be textbooks ideal for that. Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: A good text book for cognitive science is https://www.amazon.com/Mind-Introduction-Cognitive-Science-2nd/dp/026270109X A classic for philosophy of mind is https://www.amazon.de/s?k=Kim+Philosophy+of+mind

Comment: Here is a link for [*Philosophy of Mind* by Kim](https://www.amazon.com/Philosophy-Mind-Jaegwon-Kim/dp/0813344581/ref=sr_1_3?crid=34EZOUZ6H8KSJ&keywords=philosophy+of+mind&qid=1703611512&sprefix=philosophy+of+mind%2Caps%2C128&sr=8-3) auf Englisch. I wouldn't consider this introductory material, though. It's rather technical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Introduction to Philosophy of Mind books are all over the place in approaches, but so too are students and pedagogies.**

**For instance, a [*Philosophy of Mind: A Very Short Introduction*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Mind/lvtTEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=short%20introduction%20to%20philosophy%20of%20mind&printsec=frontcover) by Montero is an evening read for the serious undergraduate student of a prestigious university.** On the other hand at a low-performing community college, as part of a wider curriculum, it might have a place. **Thus, your approach to praxis is important in answering the question.** That being said, [Kim's *Philosophy of Mind*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Mind/a0tWDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=kim%20philosophy%20of%20mind&printsec=frontcover) is very technical, and might benefit an advanced undergraduate, but I suspect a little too technical for the average undergraduate.

**There may come suggestions of rigorous philosophy of mind revolving around cognitive science, and this might be tempting, but for undergraduates who might not have the background that the Sloan Foundation cites as foundational** (statistics, AI, neuroscience, linguistics, anthropology, and psychology), you'll now be responsible for taking a particularly narrow approach to philosophy of mind, one rooted in a highly analytical, physicalist view. If you decide to go that route, [Bermudez's *Cognitive Science: An Introduction to the Science of the Mind*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cognitive_Science/DoHCDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bermudez%20cognitive%20science&printsec=frontcover) and [Shaprio's *Embodied Cognition*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Embodied_Cognition/UBUqwAEACAAJ?hl=en) might be good adjuncts to your pedagogy.
Both are introductory level textbooks in their own right.

I've only taught mathematics and computer science, however, for a rigorous course, I'd pick three books from my collection as the core of material:

- The first is [Ryle's *Concept of Mind*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Concept_of_Mind/IFsKMBOazIoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=ryle%20concept%20of%20mind&printsec=frontcover). Of course, philosophy of mind goes back to the ancient Greeks, but a psychologist should purport to be a student of modern science related to the mind. Ryle's work represents the most famous of the anti-Cartesian movement that characterizes contemporary psychology, and has a chapter on philsophical (as opposed to psychological) behaviorism. Descartes's approach to philosophy of mind is very intuitive, so Ryle's attack on Descartes represents a serious clash of ideas to consider.
- The second work is dated, but a popular introduction to the analytical approach to understanding the putative physical origin of the mind, [Pinker's *How the Mind Works*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_the_Mind_Works/48zpLNAmTXwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Pinker%20How%20the%20Mind%20Works&printsec=frontcover). As perhaps the most famous psycholinguist on the plant, Pinker offers an approach to mind popular with contemporary psychologists and neurolinguists. These positions are consistent with the "brass knuckles" psychology that seeks to boost it's science credentials. (On a related note, [O'Donnahue's *Clinical Psychology and the Philosophy of Science*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Clinical_Psychology_and_the_Philosophy_o/CaT37IuMB9IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=philosophy%20of%20science%20psychology&printsec=frontcover) is one of the best introductory philosophy of science books out there.)
- Lastly, [John Heil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Heil) has a introductory text to philosophy of mind that has multiple editions, and starts easy and gets technical at the end. It's Routledge Press and is called [*Philosophy of Mind: A Contemporary Introduction*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Mind/Zzj3DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=john%20heil%20philosophy%20of%20mind&printsec=frontcover). It is the best textbook I have on the topic, though it does lean towards the technical.

**These materials combined, would be rigorous for a philosophy undergrad, so I'd scale back the expectations if your population isn't devoted to rigorous academics.** In Heil's text, for instance, you could pass over more technical sections, like those on radical indeterminism.

Naturally, teacher to teacher, only you really have a good understanding of your ambitions, students, pedagogy, so it's entirely possible that you can pick and choose among an assortment of "A-Very-Short-Introduction" materials to assemble something to suit the praxis you strive for. Good luck!

Comment: Ryle?  Really?   I found him to be a vacuous polemicist. https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/review/0226732967/R30LV9YTM6DI8L?ref=pf_ov_at_pdctrvw_srp

Comment: @Dcleve Nonetheless, a historically significant figure. Behaviorism represented a revolution in the metaphysics of the philosophy of mind and portended the wide swath of empirical support for fallibilism. Today, Cartesian certainty is a myth that pervades along with folk intuitions like objectivity-of-truth, one-true-logic, and Homo-economicus.

Comment: Both Ordinary Language Philosophy and Logical Positivism were dominant schools of thought and have had a massive influence on analytical philosophy, and Ryle is important to the former as Carnap is to the latter. The fact that post-linguistic turn, the notion of the category mistake is a central notion to understanding quantifier variance and natural language ontology, and that the attack on Cartesian duality is still on going (though obviously remedied by property dualism), is a testimony to his influence, not only through Dennett, but Anglo-American philosophy writ large.

Comment: All of neural identity theory, functionalist identity theory, and emergentist physicalism disagree and reject absolutely that “the concept of mind is a category mistake”. It is explicitly rejected by the neuroscience search for neural correlates of consciousness. All dualists and idealists also explicitly reject this claim.  Use of a text that basically every current thinker considers grossly wrong is not something I would think useful in an intro class.     A brief historical aside on this peculiar idea could be of interest, but the main text???

Comment: @Dcleve The main text I recommended is Heil's. As for Ryle's critique invoking the category mistake, I don't agree with it any more than you do. But the fact that his critique has drawn such empassioned language against it is precisely why it should be studied. It's as controversial as Skinner's behaviorism. I merely claim, as a quietist, that all metaphysical disputes really revolve around accusations and counteraccusations of category mistake, a linguistic claim. I take Hirsch's claims about [quanitifier variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_variance) a step further.

Answer (score 3):

The single best book on philosophy of mind I have read is Susan Blackmore's A Very Short Introduction to Consciousness.  She is a clear writer, and does an outstanding job focusing on experiments and what they tell us.  Emphasizing the practical aspects of how to test mental theorizing -- seems like a great way to motivate your psych students.  Here is my review:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1C1TJFIWBZ8ZQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0198794738  Blackmore's focus on Delusionism, shorter treatment of materialist theories that treat consciousness as real, dismissal of dualism, and ignoring of idealism all suggest this book would best be supplemented by some additional materials, but are not fatal problems.

Blackmore has written a full length textbook as well, which I have not read. That would possibly be a better choice for your class.  Here is a link:  [https://www.amazon.com/Consciousness-Emily-Troscianko-Susan-Blackmore/dp/1138801313/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=blackmore+consciousness&qid=1703625717&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138801313)

Comment: But despite my defense as an object of study, contemporary philosophy of mind has shown how little justice is done to the topic until after the cognitive psychological revolution. :D I've added this to my things-to-read list, thanks!

Comment: @JD Well, the behaviorist denial that consciousness matters at all, DID make understanding either minds or conscious basically impossible.  Whatever alternative approach expelled this idiocy was, of course, “essential” to enable useful study of mind and consciousness.  That does not mean cognitivism is the “right” way to do Psychology or Phil of Mind, but cognitive thinkers certainly deserve credit for salvaging a science and philosophy that had been stuck in a dead end.

Comment: All of which are perfectly valid points that should be made to students. :D Perhaps it's time for you to write your philosophical novel on these matters.